# In Jenkins, on a Windows remote connected through Cygwin sshd, how to run an sh pipeline step?

Tags: jenkins, cygwin, jenkins-pipeline

We are porting our Jenkins pipeline to work on Windows environments.

The Jenkins' master connects to our Windows remote -named `winremote`- using Cygwin sshd.
As described on [this page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+slaves+and+Cygwin), the `Remote root directory` of the node is given as a plain Windows path (in this case, it is set to *C:\cygwin64\home\jenkins\jenkins-slave-dir*)

This minimal pipeline example:

```
    node("winremote")
    {
        echo "Entering Windows remote"
        sh "ls -l"
    }
```

fails with the error:

```
[Pipeline] echo
Entering Windows rmeote
[Pipeline] sh
[C:\cygwin64\home\jenkins\jenkins-slave-dir\workspace\proto-platforms] Running shell script
sh: C:\cygwin64\home\jenkins\jenkins-slave-dir\workspace\proto-platforms@tmp\durable-a739272f\script.sh: command not found
```

SSHing into the Windows remote, I was able to see that Jenkins actually created `workspace` subdirectory in `C:\cygwin64\home\jenkins\jenkins-slave-dir`, but it is left empty.

Is there a known way to use the `sh` pipeline step on such a remote ?

Answer (score 0):

A [PR from blatinville](https://github.com/jenkinsci/durable-task-plugin/pull/33), that was merged a few hours after this question, solves this first issue. 
Sadly, it introduces another problem, described in the ticket [JENKINS-41225](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41225), with the error:

```
nohup: failed to run command 'sh': No such file or directory
```

There is a proposed [PR for a quickfix](https://github.com/jenkinsci/durable-task-plugin/pull/36) of this issue.

Then there is a last problem with how the durable-task-plugin evaluate if a task is still alive using 'ps', with [another PR fixing it](https://github.com/jenkinsci/durable-task-plugin/pull/35).

### Temporary solution

Until those (or equivalent) fixes are applied, one could compile a Cygwin compatible durable-task-plugin with the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/Adnn/durable-task-plugin.git -b cygwin_fixes
cd durable-task-plugin/
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Which notably generates *target/durable-task.hpi* file, which can be used to replace the *durable-task.jpi* file as installed by Jenkins in its *plugins* folder. It is then required to restart Jenkins.